# How do I place a checkbox on all cells in a repeater?

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, repeater

I have a repeater. I want to distribute documents in a class. The first column contains student names. In the first line, there are books defined for the class.

What I want to do is keep track of whether the books were given or not. For example, şebneme, mathematics Turkish English book was given. He was given English and mathematics. I want to place a checkbox on the matrix plane. I will keep it true or false. I'm dynamically creating checboxes, but I can't place them in the repeater. How do I do it?

`<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Visible="false">`
                            `<asp:TextBox ID="txtsayi1" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>`
                         `<asp:TextBox ID="txtsayi2" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>`

```
                       ` <table id="mytable3" class="table table-striped table-bordered second" style="width: 98%">`


                            `<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rowRepeater" OnItemDataBound="rowRepeater_ItemBound">`

                                `<HeaderTemplate>`
                                   ` <thead>`

                                      `  <tr>`
                                       `     <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="headerRepeater">`
                                              `  <ItemTemplate>`
                                                   ` <th><%# Eval("DokumanAdi") %></th>`
                                             `   </ItemTemplate>`
                                            `</asp:Repeater>`
                                      `  </tr>`
                                    `</thead>`
                                  `  <tbody>`
                                `</HeaderTemplate>`
                               ` <ItemTemplate>`
                                  `  <tr>`

                                        `<td><%# Eval("OgrenciAdi") %></td>`

                                    `   <%-- <td>
                                           <asp:CheckBox ID="chkbx" runat="server" /></td>--%>`
                                    `</tr>`

                               ` </ItemTemplate>`
                               ` <FooterTemplate>`
                                `</FooterTemplate>`
                            `</asp:Repeater>`
                           ` </tbody>`
                       ` </table>`

                   ` </asp:Panel>`
```

This is my frontend codes.I have got a button click event. when ı click button 
`for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)`
       `{`
           `for (int t = 0; t < i; t++)`
            `{`
              `CheckBox cbx = new CheckBox();`

```
          `  cbx.ID = "cbx" + t;`
          `  rowRepeater.Controls.Add(cbx);`

       ` }`
   ` }`
```

ItemBound event,

`protected void rowRepeater_ItemBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)` 
     `{`

```
    `  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header) ` 
    `  {
        `  DataTable dt1 = db.Doldur("select * from tblDokumanTuru"); ` 

       `   Repeater headerRepeater = e.Item.FindControl("headerRepeater") as Repeater; ` 
        `  headerRepeater.DataSource = dt1; ` 
        `  headerRepeater.DataBind(); ` 

        `  txtsayi2.Text = dt1.Rows.Count.ToString(); ` 


     ` } ` 


     ` if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) ` 
   `   { ` 

    `  } ` 


`  } `
```

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried and what errors you are getting. Also please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)